# Create table can scroll in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How can I create a table to show high scores, it has 2 or 3 columns (or table ) and can scroll left or right like:

[image]

I can't find any tutorial or example about this, please help me.

Comment: Are you using SpriteBuilder as well?

Comment: i using cocos2d v3 RC2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Procedure

The API for `ScrollView` objects strongly resembles that of `UIKit`.

The basic idea of it is to put all your content on a `CCNode` that you wish to scroll. (You should make sure the `contentSize` of the node is the exact size of your desired scrollable area).

After constructing this you would set this as your `CCScrollView` s content node.
Note here that the `contentNode`must be the child of the `CCScrollView`, which is added automatically if you use the setter.

Set up other parameters like *pagination* , *scrolling* or whatever you like by checking out the public API in the `CCScollView` header. If you are confused about how to use some of these check out a `UIScrollView` tutorial.

### Example Code

This is some example code I have whipped up for you. It puts red 10 red `CCNodeColor` *boxes* on the screen that you can scroll through *horizontally*.

```
CCNode *boxContainer = [CCNode node];
for (int i= 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    CCNodeColor *colorNode = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor redColor] width:50.0f height:50.0f];
    colorNode.position = ccp(i * 60.0f, 25.0f);
    [boxContainer addChild:colorNode];
}
boxContainer.contentSize = CGSizeMake( 600.0f, 50.0f);
boxContainer.position = ccp(0.0f, 0.0f);
boxContainer.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

CCScrollView *scroll = [CCScrollView node];
scroll.contentNode = boxContainer;
scroll.position = ccp(0.0f, -self.scene.boundingBox.size.height / 2.0f);
scroll.verticalScrollEnabled = NO;

[self addChild:scroll];
```

Note that the **y position is flipped**.

### Bonus tips

- You can use **SpriteBuilder** to set up your Cocos2D-iphone visuals, where you can drag and drop scroll views for example; it's a real time saver once you are comfortable with Cocos
- In my example code I have set up the boxes positions manually. You can and **should** avoid this with the use of `CCLayoutBox` objects which you can also setup in **Sprite Builder** (Think about this as a one dimensional *Collection View*)